# Can one use vivio instead of biologio?

Tags: word-formation

For the sake of consistency, is it possible to use the -i- affix in this context?

Indeed *life* is *vivo* so the *study of life* should be *vivio*.

**Souce**: http://www.romaniczo.com/esperanto/gramatiko/grammar_13.html

> -i-: Science, theory, study, art, system:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because *-i-* could be considered a suffix used when there is a root that names the professional doing that work:

```
biolog/o - person
biologi/o - science

geograf/o - person
geografi/o - science
```

Affixes and suffixes have their limitations. Not all of them can be used with all roots. Take *mal* for example, *malhundo* would probably not have any universally coherent meaning. Meanwhile *-et-* will work with almost anything: *hund-et-o*, *dom-et-o*, ..., *tim-et-o*.

Note also that *-i-* with that meaning is not officially recognized as a suffix, and you will find *biologio* listed as *biologi/o*. That's important.

Not all roots are born equal (Fundamentaj, Oficialaj, Zamenhofaj, Novaj) and the same applies to suffixes/prefixes.

Also, some word elements are found/defined *a posteriori*. And not only by linguists, the speakers do that too. The adverbs *baldetaux*/*apenetaŭ* are examples of speakers doing just that. The thing is, since those elements were extracted from a set of words, they are not freely combinable. The neofficial suffix *-i-* belongs to that category.

You can find more information on *-i-* in [this page from PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/neoficialaj_afiksoj/sufiksoj/i.html).

Comment: You could use the pseudosuffixes _[ologi](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/neoficialaj_afiksoj/sufiksoj/ologi.html)_ and _[olog](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/neoficialaj_afiksoj/sufiksoj/olog.html)_ to create words like _vivologio_ and _vivologo_, which to me would be like saying in English _lifeology_ and _lifeologist_. Is it possible? Yes. Is it worth using? Very dubious.

Answer (score 2):

No, because -i- is not a suffix for sciences.

You could use a word like "vivoscienco", but "biologio" would probably be better understood, because it's more often and usual.

Comment: I just added a reference to my question.

Comment: The unofficial ending _-i-_ is usable for sciences only, if the root word ends in  _-log/_: _biologio, psikologio_. Compare with _biologo, psikologo_ for practioner of the science.